# Whisper and pyannote 3.1 : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, openai-whisper, diarization, speaker-diarization

I'm using [this script](https://gist.github.com/hbredin/049f2b629700bcea71324d2c1e7f8337)  to diarize then transcribe speach using pyannote.audio and whisper. Using pyannote 2.1, it works perfectly, but then, when I change the version used to the latest (3.1), I get an error when running this line :

```py
for segment, _, speaker in who_speaks_when1.itertracks(yield_label=True):
    waveform, sample_rate = audio.crop(audio_file1, segment)
    text = model.transcribe(waveform.squeeze().numpy())["text"]
    print(f"{segment.start:06.1f}s {segment.end:06.1f}s {speaker}: {text}")
```

When I should have the transcript of the audio I'm using, I get the error message `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`.

pyannote 2.1 works fine, so so far I'm happy to use it, but I'm very frustrated not to be able to see what the latest versions do.

Any idea ?